# D3.js Multi-Series Chart with Y value tracking

Tags: javascript, csv, svg, charts, d3.js

**Working solution:** Right now I'm working on styling and on solving some of the issues regarding my problem with creating chart consisting of multiple-data series with values tracking. I will try as soon as I can to give you a sample of working code soo if anybody will came across the same or similar problem as I did, could work on it as a base. For now most of the tips which I used are in the comments below.

---

This will be my first question on StackOverflow and I'm looking forward to seeing what answers you might have to my problem.

Recently I got project in which I have to write Javascript code for generating charts and in which I would be able to read Y values from every line of the chart at the same time. I very new to D3 framework and by now I'm able to read csv data, create multi-series chart and track and read Y value but only when I'm creating chart from a single data series. I was trying to create multiple similar functions that would track data from diferent series of data but it won't work and in console i see that the Y is showing as null from what I can understand. I was using examples from D3 website to try to learn it and for now code will be very similar to those examples.

Later on I would need to do some other things with it but i think that after solving that problem i will be able to keep going. There will be like:

- reduce data from csv by code because I will need to delete header infromation
- change visual style of the chart and edit axis scaling

For now I have something like that. Sorry if it is a little bit messy but I'm still learning and trying a lot of different things. I have added also screenshot from what it looks like for me and some console information that i could get. I hope it will help you guys see what I'm doing wrong and what I would need to learn. Also this is not my only approach and it would be too long to show them all.

**EDIT:** I'm trying a little bit different approach. On the bottom of the page i will show what I have done by now.

**EDIT2:** Sorry if i was't precise enough about my goal. What I'm trying to do with this is I want to be able to read all Y-axis values of drawn lines (it will be 4 of them) at the same time on one X-axis value. I have added screenshot of the second code in which I'm able to read only one Y-axis value and can't read the over one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 200},
    //-margin.left
    width = 960 - margin.right,
    height = 750 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%M-%d %H:%M").parse,
    //dodane do sledzenia myszy i rysowania kuleczek
    bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left,
    formatValue = d3.format(",.2f"),
    formatCurrency = function(d) { return "$" + formatValue(d); };

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.transfers); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data2.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  });

  var bitrates = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, transfers: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  console.log(bitrates);

  //data.sort(function(a, b) {
    //return a.date - b.date;
  //});

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([
    d3.min(bitrates, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.transfers; }); }),
    d3.max(bitrates, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.transfers; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Transfers");

  var chart = svg.selectAll(".chart")
      .data(bitrates)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "chart");

  chart.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      //.attr("d", line);
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  chart.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.transfers) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em");
      //.text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  //sledzenie myszy i rysowanie kuleczek
  var focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .style("display", "none");

  focus.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

  focus.append("text")
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em");

  svg.append("g").append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
      .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
      .on("mousemove", mousemove);

  function mousemove() {
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.value) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text(formatCurrency(d.value));
  }
});

</script>
```

It looks like for me like this:
[Generated chart](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzUzmWcbRT0ZS0txTElMRTVDV2c&usp=sharing)
CSV data file looks like this:

```
date,Średni wych.:,Średni wch.:,Maks. wych.:,Maks. wch.:
2014-02-14 15:40,86518717581,101989990772,88304882317,108036052338
2014-02-14 16:00,85739038102,98312113056,87060053514,107154908503
```

Some over information that I inspected while trying to understand what is wrong:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
name: "Średni wych.:"
values: Array[504]
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
name: "Maks. wych.:"
values: Array[504]
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]
100: Object
date: Thu Jan 16 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)
transfers: 49305177944
__proto__: Object
101: Object
date: Thu Jan 16 2014 01:20:00 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)
transfers: 42169641572
__proto__: Object
102: Object
date: Thu Jan 16 2014 01:40:00 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)
transfers: 39400112189
__proto__: Object
103: Object
104: Object
105: Object
106: Object
107: Object
108: Object
109: Object
110: Object
```

I would really appreciate any help from you. I know some Object Oriented Programming, HTML, CSS, but for now I wasn't really working with any framework and it is fun to learn but on the over hand could be really frustrating while trying to figure out what the heck I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

Now I'm trying drawing two lines separately. It is working great and it could make it easier for me to change lines style later on. Now i need to use mousemove function for each of those lines. Then it would be fairly easy to just pass readed values to some variables and show them in some box or something.

This is the code for the my second try(sorry for post getting long):

[Screenshot for the second code is called Chart2.jpg](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzUzmWcbRT0ZS0txTElMRTVDV2c&usp=sharing)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="d3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 100},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse,
    bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left,
    formatValue = d3.format(",.2f"),
    formatCurrency = function(d) { return "$" + formatValue(d); };

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.open); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
    d.open = +d['open data'];
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.date - b.date;
  });

  x.domain([data[0].date, data[data.length - 1].date]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.close, d.open); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .style("stroke", "red")
      .attr("d", valueline2);

  var focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .style("display", "none");

  focus.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

  focus.append("text")
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em");

  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
      .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
      .on("mousemove", mousemove1)
      .on("mousemove", mousemove2);

  function mousemove1() {
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus = focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.close) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text(formatCurrency(d.close));
    }

  function mousemove2() {
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus = focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.open) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text(formatCurrency(d.open));
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: I posted a different approach that could help me solving this problem. If anyone have suggestions what to do next I would really appreciate.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is?  Is it that you want a tooltip that shows the y-values for all the lines at the same x-value as the mouse?  You should be able to do that with the mousemove function you have.  Or is it that you only want the value for the particular line under the mouse?  In which case you will (a) need to bind a data array to the `<path>` element or its parent `<g>` element (your second code sample does this), and (b) accept that data array as a parameter to the mousemove function: `function mousemove(pathData){... var d0=pathData[i - 1]; ...}.

Comment: Yeah. Reading all the Y-axis values on one X-axis value was what i was trying to do. Sorry for that. I was trying to apply b) sollution to my first code but i couldn't make it work and the second code is only reading one Y-axis value. I will try to find out what is wrong with it but i would be gratefull for more advices. I working on it for just like 5 days and at this point I feel i got really stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got all the basic code there, you just need to get it all to run at the same time.

The first problem is that you're setting two different "mousemove" event handlers on the same elements.  [Unless you use namespaces to distinguish them, the second function just replaces the first](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on), so your first function is never getting called.  Rather than creating two event handlers with different namespaces, it's much easier to just put all your event-handling code into one function.

The second problem is that you only have one "focus" element, and so even if you did run both functions to set the two different tooltip contents and position, only the second version would be displayed, because it just replaces the first.

So to recap, you need to: create a tooltip/focus element for *each* path, and then have one event-handling function that sets all the values and positions according to the appropriate column of your data file.

To keep the code concise, and to allow you to quickly switch from two lines to four or more, I'm going to suggest that you create the focus elements as a data-joined selection, where the data is an array of column names:

```
var columnNames = d3.keys( data[0] ) //grab the key values from your first data row
                                     //these are the same as your column names
                  .slice(1); //remove the first column name (`date`);

var focus = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(columnNames)
  .enter().append("g") //create one <g> for each columnName
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .style("display", "none");

focus.append("circle") //add a circle to each
    .attr("r", 4.5);

focus.append("text")  //add a text field to each
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em");
```

Now, when you show or hide focus in the mouseover/mouseout events, it will show or hide *all* the tooltips:

```
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", mousemove);
```

But what should you do in your mousemove function?  The first part, figuring out the nearest x-value (date) is the same.  But then you have to set the text and position of each focus tooltip according to the values in the correct column.  You can do this because each focus element has a column name bound to it as a data object, and d3 will pass that data object as the first parameter to any function you pass in to a d3 method:

```
function mousemove() {
  var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
    i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
    d0 = data[i - 1],
    d1 = data[i],
    d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0; 
       //d is now the data row for the date closest to the mouse position

   focus.attr("transform", function(columnName){
         return "translate(" + x( d.date ) + "," + y( d[ columnName ] ) + ")";
   });
   focus.select("text").text(function(columnName){
         //because you didn't explictly set any data on the <text>
         //elements, each one inherits the data from the focus <g>

         return formatCurrency(d[ columnName ]);
   });
}
```

By the way, you can use this same structure -- use the column names as data, and then use that name in a function to grab the correct data value -- to create all your lines with the same code, without having to create separate data arrays.  Let me know if you have difficulty implementing that.

Comment: Than you very much for your answer. It will definitely come in handy and I will try it when I can. Yesterday when I was struggling in finding some solution I founded this post on Stack Overflow. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003832/d3-x-value-mouseover-function-returns-nan) and [link](http://jsfiddle.net/U4CGz/7/). I was soo happy that finally I can start working on it. If I encounter any problem while implementing your solution I let you know. And I'm wondering. Can I apply custom colors to the color function used for example on the first version of code?

Comment: To create a custom color scale, you just create a [d3 ordinal scale] and set the domain and range yourself.  `var color = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["max", "min", "mean"]).range(["red", "blue", "green"])`.  The domain values should match your column names that you are using for the data, and then you can pass the color scale as a function like `.attr('stroke', color)`.

Comment: I have another problem. Now I'm trying to add fields outside the chart where I will see values of every line while hovering. I want it to looks similar like circles are drawn. [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzUzmWcbRT0ZS0txTElMRTVDV2c&usp=sharing) (text file Chart). It is showing me only last value and when i try add . enter() nothing is happening. I will have another problem to solve later on. I will have to replace X-axis labels and ticks with something like (Week 1, Week 2...) without changing to much cause I might need to show in Tooltip date like (2014-01-01 00:00).

Comment: You're adding the text within a function for modifying the circles, so each time that function runs the same text element will be selected modified to have the data for the current circle.  If you want multiple text elements, you need to do a data-join all at once to an array of all of the data elements.  For your axis, check out the [formatting options for dates](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-format) and the [tickFormat function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-tickFormat).  For any further questions, create a new SO question so others can help.